# SQL - Add a letter prefix if the column starts with a number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on a project that is messing up when any results start with a number, for example 01.

I've tried to spend some time on how to apply a prefix to the column only if it starts with a number, though I'm stuck on the conditional part.

`SELECT 'a' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) FROM table`

How could I apply the conditional to a select only if ID starts with a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `case`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN id LIKE '[0-9]%' THEN 'a' +  id
             ELSE id
        END) as newID
FROM table;
```

`ID` is presumably a string to start with, so you don't need to cast it to a `varchar()`.